# Delete Uploaded Image from CKEditor

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor in my Laravel application. I want to create an option to delete the uploaded image via CKEditor if the user is not needed that image. Please help me in this. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

there is something called [CKFinder](https://ckeditor.com/ckfinder/) 
maybe it will helps to find the file and remove it